# ¿Como hago una conexion de base de datos PHP a ionic 3?

Tags: php, ionic, typescript, ionic2, angular4

Hice una conexión a la base de datos con una api PHPcon el framework slim y aun así siento que esta mal hecha por que me manda error de CORS, se hizo todas las soluciones posibles .

Comment: Cual es el error que te da? que no entiendo la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes indicar en tu php la aceptación de acceso desde origenes fuera de tu servidor

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Esa linea deberías de colocarla al inicio de tu código php antes de cualquier salida de respuesta.

tambien puedes limitar el aceso a una ip o dominio, o  grupos de estos

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: hitcel.com");
```

De esa manera solo le damos acceso a la api al dominio o peticiones que provengan del dominio hitcel.com por ejemplo.

Tambien puedes especificar que metodos acepta tu api:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
```

Esto aplica para cualquier peticion que se reciba desde agentes externos a tu server, bien sea desde APPs ionic, phonegap, android, etc.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice Carlos Quintera es la via correcta, tienes que darle acceso a los origenes fuera de tu servidor.... Si tienes Mac, un tip rapido seria usar la herramienta de desarrollador de Safari y desactivar el CORS, y todo fluye sin problemas.

Si no tienes activa la herramienta puedes ir a:
Preferencias -> Avanzado. y aqui activar la casilla "Ver menu de desarrollo en la barra".

Cuando ya la tienes activa, selecciona "Desarrollo" y luego seleccionar la opcion "Desactivar restricciones CORS"

Saludos